# Problem with BasicView and CameraType.SPRING

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d, pv3d

Working with the BasicView class in Papervision 2.0, I'm getting an error when compiling:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property SPRING through a 
>   reference with static type Class.

If I comment out the access of that static property and add the constant value manually, it works as expected:

```
case "Spring": //CameraType.SPRING:
    _camera = new SpringCamera3D();
    _camera.target = DisplayObject3D.ZERO;      
    break;
```

Here's where it's being defined in the `CameraType` class:

```
/*
 * the SPRING constant defines a SpringCamera3D
 */
public static var SPRING        :String = "Spring";
```

Any ideas as to what would cause this to occur? My first guess is a conflict with another static/const var as I've run into problems with Actionscript conflicts like that. Perhaps this ASCollada class (also in the PV lib):

```
public static const DAE_SPRING_ELEMENT:String = "spring";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly pv3d related but, could help ... 
It sounds more like a conflict between an older version and the newer. Could it happen that you have referenced two concurrent versions/classpath. I've had this kind of problem forgetting to remove a SWC containing the same (but slightly different) classes as the imported ones.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! That was exactly the problem. I had 1.5 in my app-wide imports as well as 2.0 in the